# Using reflect to call method of struct inside struct method

Tags: go, reflection

How can I use reflect to call method of struct, inside a struct method? e.g:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type T struct{}

func (t *T) New() {
    value := getDynamicValue()
    method := reflect.ValueOf(&t).MethodByName(value)
    fmt.Println(method)
}

func (t *T) fake() {
    fmt.Println("Fake!")
}

func main() {
    var t T
    t.New()
}

func getDynamicValue() string {
    return "fake"
}
```

The following code will print `<invalid reflect.Value>` even though `fake` exists.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You can only reflect on exported members.

Comment: @Adrian if I change to `Fake`, still doesn't work.

Comment: `t` is already a pointer, `&t` is `**t` (https://play.golang.org/p/TIylbXFRiNb)

Comment: T has no method Fake (or fake) or any method at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems are that:

- `&t` is passed to `ValueOf` instead of `t`
- the `fake` method is not exported

Here is a working example:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type T struct{}

func (t *T) New() {
    value := getDynamicValue()
    method := reflect.ValueOf(t).MethodByName(value)
    fmt.Println(method)
}

func (t *T) Method() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world!")
}

func main() {
    var t T
    t.New()
}

func getDynamicValue() string {
    return "Method"
}
```

Outputs

`0xec820`

[Try it yourself](https://play.golang.org/p/r41oPdF7tR7)

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the method and call it:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type T struct{}

func (t *T) New() {
    value := getDynamicValue()
    method := reflect.ValueOf(t).MethodByName(value)
    fmt.Println(method.Call(nil))
}

func (t *T) Fake() {
    fmt.Println("Fake!")
}

func main() {
    var t T
    t.New()
}

func getDynamicValue() string {
    return "Fake"
}
```